# Rotating icon-refresh

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, font-awesome

I am following [this](http://www.elijahmanor.com/animating-a-twitter-bootstrap-icon-with-css3/) example.

I am still a bit new to CSS3 and not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a simple website using MVC4, with twitter bootstrap and fontawesome. I am trying to get the refresh button animate while I wait for a jQquery post to complete.

I've put the CSS, as specified in the example, in its own file and it is being referenced correctly.

I have tried using the jQuery as both a file and just simply in a script tag on the page.

No matter which conbination I try, I can't get the refresh icon to rotate.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is there any other way to rotate an icon?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the spinner while it's there? if you're following the example verbatim, it has a click event handler. You'd want to add it in a ready function `$(function() { //here });`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you're using font-awesome, you can add the class `fa-spin` to your element, it's built in and requires you to add 7 extra characters!! Beats manually writing the css3 animation and toggling the class with javascript.

Just make an element like so,

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
```

and watch that puppy spin.

Refer to [fontawesome's spinning docs](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#spinning) if you have any concerns

Comment: Just a warning to anyone else that wants to use this solution : Firefox renders a "wobbly" spinning icon. I am on version 28.0. Here is a [link](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/671) to the issue at FA's github.

Answer (score 1):

Use this classes of fontAwesome icons: `class="icon-refresh icon-spin"`
Link for fontAwesome icons: [fontAwesome icons website](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/get-started/)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please take a lokk at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer